# Synology DSM helloworld package compile error written C++

Tags: c++, linux, synology

Please help me.
I try to compile hello world package written c++.
My environment is 
    OS : Ubuntu 14.4,and 
    synology toolchain is  bromolow 64bit compiler,
But I cannot get helloworld.cgi. I don't know the reason.
Source code are

```
#include "webman.h"

#include <string>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <synosdk/proc.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    WebMan _cgi;
    Json::Value out;
    out["uname"] = "helloworld";
    out["ret"] = true;
    out["success"] = true;
    _cgi.WriteHeader();
    _cgi.WriteBody(out);
    return 0;
}
```

and make file is

```
.PHONY: all clean
.SUFFIXES: .cgi
CXXFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config libdsm --cflags)
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config libdsm --libs)
CXXFLAGS+=-I/usr/syno/nclude/gpl \
          -I/usr/syno/include/synocgi \
# source files

SRC=${cgi_name}.cpp
CGI=$(SRC:%.cpp=../%.cgi)

all: $(CGI)

../%.cgi: %.cpp
    echo $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f core *~ *.o $(CGI)
```

I got such error

```
======= Run build script =======

make: *** No rule to make target `distclean'.  Stop.
==> cgi
==> js
<== js
/usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/bin/i686-linux-gnu-ccache-g++ -o ../helloworld.cgi helloworld.cpp -I/usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/include -DSYNO_X64 -O2 -I/usr/syno/include -g -DSYNO_PLATFORM=X64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=400 -L/usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/syno/lib -Wl,-rpath-link -Wl,/usr/syno/lib -L/usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/syno/lib -L/source/libsynocgi/lib -L/usr/syno/sqlite3/lib/ -L/source/libsynoacl/lib/ -L/source/libsynosdk/gpl/ -L/source/google-authenticator-1.x -lsynocgi -ljson -lsynowireless-core -lsynoacl -lsynogpl -lsynocoregpl -lsynobandwidth -lsynowimax -lsynosdk -lsynocore -lcrypt -lnet -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lxml2 -lattr -lm -ldl -lz -lsqlite3 -lgoogleauth -ldsm
/usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.2.1/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lnet
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../helloworld.cgi] Error 1
make[1]: *** [cgi] Error 2
make: *** [ui] Error 2

There is no install-dev scripts for helloworld.

Time cost: 00:00:03 [Build-->helloworld]
I got the following error:
make[2]: *** [../helloworld.cgi] Error 1
make[1]: *** [cgi] Error 2
make: *** [ui] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you installed all the required libraries? After installing the libraries run the make file..

Comment: Thank you for answer.Yes ,I have installed the library ds-x64-4.3 and toolchain bromolow.But I got such error.Please help me.

Comment: please help me.I am waiting for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm too late:) Via the error message I guess you need add extra rule on your Makefile for **distclean**, even empty. At the same time, you also need to add install-dev script, like your build script and install script.

Without the above error message, your source code link -lnet but the tool chain does not find it. I think you need to give a path for this library (I'm not sure the build env has **libnet** or not).